# Woocommerce: How to add a specific action when the add to cart button is clicked?

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm using Woocommerce one page checkout for a variable subscription product. It's a bit confusing for the user because my options are radio buttons and many of them don't realise that they must click the 'Add to Cart' button before they can enter their Billing / Shipping details and complete the payment. I want to hide the Billing / Shipping form until the 'Add to Cart' button is clicked so that it is clearer to customers what they need to do.
Is there a hook or filter that I can use for the Add to Cart button? I'm using custom CSS to make `#column2 {visibility:hidden;}` and when the "Add to Cart" button is clicked I want to change the visibility back to display it.